# What is the built-in function A of numpy array.A?

Tags: python, numpy

Recently I read a line of code that confused me:

```
pointsInCurrCluster = dataSet[nonzero(clusterAssment[:, 0].A == i)[0], :]
```

The author did not define the function for `A`, so I assume that `.A` is some kind of built-in function. Does anyone know what it is?

Comment: And what is `clusterAssment[:, 0]`? It can be user defined class/container returning some objects that have `A` as a parameter.

Comment: clusterAssment[:, 0]is a 2-d array. I looked through his coding, i can not find any related class or container returning some objects that have A as parameter.That is why I assume it is some kind of built in function.

Comment: For a clearer example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57867223/562769

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so in this way I think its is proparty of scipy matrix returning nparray:

```
In [115]: mtx = sp.matrix([1,2,3])    
In [116]: mtx.A
Out[116]: array([[1, 2, 3]])
```

`A` is getter/shortcut for [getA](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.getA.html#numpy.matrix.getA).

Comment: so what is A exactly?Thanks

Comment: @user12551 A property is a function that acts like a it's just a regular attribute. It's like a getter or setter method in Java with a little bit less boilerplate.

Comment: @user12551 I amended the answer.

Comment: To be picky - `np.matrix` is a function that creates a `numpy` subclass, `Matrix`.  To create a sparse matrix you use `sparse.csr_matrix()` (or one of the other sparse formats).  But both kinds of matrix have this `.A` property.

Answer (score 1):

In https://github.com/skodali1/python-machine-learning/blob/master/kmeansclusteringalgo.py
(found by google search for 'python clusterAssment'

```
from numpy import *
clusterAssment = matrix(zeros((m,2)))
...
ptsInClust = dataSet[nonzero(clusterAssment[:,0].A==cent)[0]]
```

In this case `clusterAssment` is a `numpy.matrix` object.  This is like a `numpy.ndarray`, except it is always 2d, and has MATLAB like matrix operators.

```
clusterAssment.A
```

just turns the matrix into a regular `numpy.array`, probably so it can be passed to `numpy.nonzero`.

`scipy.sparse` implements sparse matrices, which also have this `.A` property.  But based on this code, I don't think that applies here.

Answer (score 0):

`.A` means 'change the data type from a matrix to an array'

For example:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

So, in python you can get result of a conditional check on each element of an array by writing a statement like: arr > 3. What it does is, for an array arr = [[1,2,3],[3,4,5]] the output you will have is [[False,False,False],[False,True,True]]. Now having said that you need an array to do this. That is what a .A does in python, it gives you an array representation of the matrix. Now, clusterAssment[:, 0].A == i, gives you conditional check answer for every row and first column against the value i. nonzero(clusterAssment[:, 0].A == i) converts the conditional check to index of rows and columns which Satisfy the condition. More details here: [nonZero](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) . Now, since clusterAssment is a 2-D array the nonzero(~)[0] gives the rows which have the value i as 1st element, and dataSet[nonzero(clusterAssment[:, 0].A == i)[0], :] gives all those respective tuples from dataset.