# What is csr_matrix.A?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I've recently seen something like this:

```
import numpy as np
row = np.array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2])
col = np.array([0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2])
data = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
csr_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(3, 3)).A
```

In this case, it returns an numpy array:

```
array([[1, 0, 2],
       [0, 0, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]], dtype=int64)
```

This seems to be simply a non-sparse representation of the sparse matrix, but I cannot find it in the [`csr_matrix` docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html). Does anybody know for sure what the `.A` does?

Comment: It's 'short' for `.toarray()`

Answer (score 1):

the `.A is not from`crs_matrix, it is from `numpy`:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.A.html

Comment: How exactly does it come from there? I see no "inheritance path" from `numpy.matrix`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27219479/numpy-array-a-what-is-the-built-in-function-a

Comment: Cool, thank you :-)

Comment: It's not inherited from `np.matrix`.  It's just an imitation.

Comment: Ok. Do you have any idea where I can find this in the code?